# File Dialog Delay

Tags: windows-8.1

Recently, I've noticed that the standard (Windows 8.1) file dialog always causes a delay of around 5-7 seconds after it's closed.  Both for open and save scenarios.

It happens on all applications.  I even tried writing a small MFC program to test this, which only opens a file dialog and then displays the selected file path.

The dialog closes, but the application is blocked until 5-7 seconds pass, at which time the result is shown.   This also happens if the file dialog cancel button is pressed.

Any idea how to fix this annoying thing?

Comment: Did you try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) to see whether it makes any difference?

Comment: Behavior remains the same after boot